# Insert data into two temporary tables using a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2005

I have a stored procedure whose data looks like below

[image: Stored procedure]

Now what I want is, I want to insert its data into two different *temp table*

First temp table will have these columns

```
Doc_type, Doc_No, No_of_days
```

Second temp table will have columns

```
Username, DocType, No_of_days
```

I tried like this:

```
CREATE TABLE #table1 
(
    Doc_type varchar(55),
    Doc_No varchar(55),
    No_of_days varchar(55),
)

INSERT INTO #table1
```

But it throws an error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'END'.

Here is my complete stored procedure:

```
Alter procedure GET_INWARD_REMINDER_REPORT 
AS 
BEGIN 
    Select
        U.first_name + ' ' + U.last_name UserName, 
        TH.User_ID, 
        TY.Type_desc Document_Type, 
        RA.mkey Reporting_To,
        U.Email AS UserEmail, 
        RAU.Email AS RA1_Email, 
        RAU.first_name + ' ' + RAU.last_name RAName, 
        TH.Doc_No, 
        DATEDIFF(DAY, TH.LastAction_DateTime, GETDATE()) - DATEDIFF(WK, TH.LastAction_DateTime, GETDATE()) AS No_Of_Days_Doc_Pending 
    from  
        inward_doc_tracking_hdr TH 
    inner join  
        user_mst U ON TH.User_Id = U.mkey 
    inner join 
        emp_mst M ON M.mkey = U.employee_mkey 
    inner join 
        type_mst_a TY ON TY.master_mkey = TH.doc_type 
    inner join 
        emp_mst RA ON RA.mkey = M.Reporting_To 
    inner join  
        user_mst RAU ON RAU.employee_mkey = RA.mkey 
    where 
        TH.Status_flag NOT IN (5,14)  --- 5 for close, 14 for return
        and TH.To_user IS NOT NULL 

CREATE TABLE #table1 
(   
    Doc_type varchar(55),
    Doc_No varchar(55),
    No_of_days varchar(55),
)

INSERT INTO #table1
```

Comment: Scope of temp table is till session ie once sp executed .Temp table will no longer exist ...

Comment: @sandeeprawat: I know that, but help me with how to insert into the temp table

Comment: still you need to insert data then move create table at top . and do insert into \

Comment: @sandeeprawat: yes it worked, but how to check its record of `temp1` table ?

Comment: that is why  i was telling it is useless until you are not using the result further ..  for testing do select at end

Comment: I want to use it for later, to mail to user and senior from two tables respectively

Comment: in that case create permanent table and load result (truncate table and lode data in sp)

Comment: remove comma from ` No_of_days varchar(55),` in create table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get all data to temp table then insert.

```
INSERT INTO #MainTemp
EXEC [GET_INWARD_REMINDER_REPORT];

INSERT INTO #table1
select Doc_type, Doc_No, No_of_days from #MainTemp

INSERT INTO #table2
select Username, DocType, No_of_days from #MainTemp
```

UPDATED

You can use `MainTempTable`.

```
Alter procedure GET_INWARD_REMINDER_REPORT 
AS 
BEGIN 

IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM   dbo.MainTempTable) 
  DROP TABLE dbo.MainTempTable

Select 
U.first_name + ' ' + U.last_name UserName, 
TH.User_ID, 
TY.Type_desc Document_Type, 
RA.mkey Reporting_To, 
U.Email AS UserEmail, 
RAU.Email AS RA1_Email, 
RAU.first_name + ' ' + RAU.last_name RAName, 
TH.Doc_No, 
DATEDIFF(DAY,TH.LastAction_DateTime,GETDATE()) - DATEDIFF(WK,TH.LastAction_DateTime, GETDATE()) 
AS No_Of_Days_Doc_Pending 

INTO MainTempTable

from inward_doc_tracking_hdr TH 
inner join  
user_mst U ON TH.User_Id = U.mkey 
inner join 
emp_mst M ON M.mkey = U.employee_mkey 
inner join 
type_mst_a TY ON TY.master_mkey = TH.doc_type 
inner join 
emp_mst RA ON RA.mkey = M.Reporting_To 
inner join  
user_mst RAU ON RAU.employee_mkey = RA.mkey 
where 
TH.Status_flag NOT IN (5,14) --- 5 for close, 14 for return 
and TH.To_user IS NOT NULL 

SELECT 
   userName, 
   COUNT(Doc_No) CountofDocNo
FROM 
   MainTempTable 
GROUP BY 
   userName

END
```

Comment: where should I write this query, inside or outside the SP ??

Comment: I am confused after comments Where do you want to do it?

Comment: If you want to use later, you have to insert local table  You cant this with temp table

Comment: Yes, I will be using it later to mail to users from both the tables.

Comment: Why not execute sp again?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117662/discussion-between-n-k-and-hebele).